# ipython-sql same query works with %sql but not with %%sql

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython, ipython-sql

I am querying a table using ipython-sql module.
I can execute a query with %sql without any problems. However, I just can't do
with %%sql.

```
%%sql 
SELECT DISTINCT Launch_Site AS Distinct_Launch_Site 
FROM spacex
```

It gives me an error like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Launch_Site AS Distinct_Launch_Site
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But when I try like this:

```
%sql SELECT DISTINCT Launch_Site AS Distinct_Launch_Site FROM spacex
```

I got what I wanted without any errors raised.

I just don't understand why I can't use %%sql.
In addition in some cases it works.

Example:

```
%%sql 

SELECT SUM(PAYLOAD_MASS_KG_) AS PAYLOAD_MASS_KG 
FROM spacex 
WHERE Customer = 'NASA (CRS)'
```

This one just works fine !

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what database are you using in this scenario?

I ran it with both `ipython-sql` and `JupySQL` and both seem to work fine with `Duckdb`. Since each DB behaves differently I'll need more context to help you out. Here's a sample I tried running with the penguins dataset:

[image]

JupySQL is a fork of ipython-sql with newer features and active support.
Since we're talking open source, there's an active community so you're more than welcome to [open an issue](https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql/issues/new) ticket in case you're still struggling!